# how to define and access custom iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I am trying to make a custom iterator and I am struggling with syntax part of how to define/declare and eventually access it. Below is my attempt, which results in below error:

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'int' to 'int *'
```

If someone can point me to right way to define/declare it - it would be great, for I believe my access method is standard.

**Declaration**

```
template <typename T>
class ddeque
{
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    T& begin();
    T& end();
}
```

**Definition**

```
template<typename T>
T& ddeque<T>::begin()
{
    iterator = &(this->unified_array());
    return iterator;
}

template<typename T>
T& ddeque<T>::end()
{
    iterator = &(this->unified_array + this->size());
    return iterator;
}
```

Access part --
In t*est.cpp* file

// Comparing values from custom template with standard template

```
typename ddeque<T>::iterator itt = a.begin();
typename deque<T>::iterator ittg = g.begin();
while ((itt != a.end()) && (ittg != g.end())) 
{
   if (display) 
   {
     cout << *itt << " ";
   }
   ++itt;
   ++ittg;
}
```

*P.S : I have just kept relevant part of iterator - please let me know if additional code snippet is required.*

Comment: Shouldn't `begin`/`end` return an `iterator`?

Comment: You also kept only the relevant part of the error message.. or rather what you've though was the relevant part. Big mistake.

Comment: Is `unified_array` a function or a data field?

Comment: @Buddy - Below is my original definition/declaration for which I get error definition does not match declaration                                                           Declaration:
iterator begin();

Definition:
template<typename T>
iterator ddeque<T>::begin()
{
 //iterator = &(this->unified_array());
 return &(this->unified_array());
}

error C2955: 'std::iterator': use of class template requires template argument list

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский - Its a function -----           template<typename T>
T& ddeque<T>::unified_array()

Comment: @thedreamer it should return a pointer, not a reference.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский - Thank u - that was the error !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by SO member АндрейБеньковский I was returning reference instead of pointer- correct solution for definition would be ( what got it working )

**Declaration:**

```
template <typename T>
class ddeque
{
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
}
```

**Definition**
    template
    T* ddeque::begin()
    {
        iterator = &(this->unified_array());
        return iterator;
    }

```
template<typename T>
T* ddeque<T>::end()
{
    iterator = &(this->unified_array + this->size());
    return iterator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In general:**

> how to define and access custom iterator

You should make a contaner class and an iterator class. The latter should be derived from [std::iterator<>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/). You have to specify iterator tag, return value, ect. Depending on the iterator tag, you should be implementing the operators (increment, decrement, ect.). (Or better, implement everything you can which has a maximum of logarithmic complexity, then set best iterator tag.)

So begin, and end should be returning your iterator. Take a look at some stl container implementations, they are not so hard to read.

**In your code**

ou have made a `typdef T* iterator;`. This line makes another name for the pointer to T type. For readability, and to make it easier to change later, you should be returning iterator with begin and end, so:

```
iterator begin();
iterator end();
```

In the definition of the above functions, you cannot assign a value to the iterator type, I suggest returning the pointer (or iterator), for example in end():

```
return this->unified_array + this->size();
```

I think `unified_array` is a pointer, so I used it that way.

Comment: I took below two links as reference and tried to implement it - http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-iterator-define.html#TOC1  and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60484/stl-vector-implementation  - however I am not able to understand where I am going wrong - from what is written is if I have standard array - I could typedef it way I have done and another CR link has also implemented similarly

Comment: If you want to use an iterator with `<algorithms>`, you generally would also need to specialize `iterator_traits<T>`, but pointers are already defined.